# Ember-Data model lifecycle

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember itself is awesome but its docs are cumbersome and complicated. I spent 2 weeks and haven't got a solid grasp of it yet. And most difficult part for me is how Ember-Data integrates into Ember.

For example, for the new action I create the new record of Group model in appropriate route like so:

```
model: ->
  Twicl.Group.createRecord
    access: 'public'
```

Then I catch submit event and do the following in the controller:

```
  save: (record) ->
    record.save().then =>
      @transitionTo 'groups'
```

It's expected to get to groups.index route if there are no errors and it's working, but in collection I see not only recently saved record but (I guess) its prototype with no data in attributes as well.

The rude solution is to filter model in the index controller:

```
#instead of 
model: ->
  Twicl.Block.find()
#do
model: ->
  Twicl.Block.find(isNew: false)
```

Is that it? Or I missed something? Why we can't just get a brand-new collection on controller init?

Also I would appreciate any links to the actual guides (except of official guides and API of course), all that I googled is irrelevant because of old versions of both Ember and Ember-Data. :(

Answer (score 1):

The TRANSITION document has a lot of good info about getting onto beta 1/2 : https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Instead of

```
Twicl.Group.createRecord()
```

now you should do

```
this.store.createRecord('group')
```

And instead of

```
Twicl.Block.find({isNew: false})
```

you'd do

```
this.store.find('block',{isNew : false})
```

Comment: Thanks! Right after posting I discovered that I've been using 0.14 version of Ember Data which is not what I was going to do :) But the main issue is that it's common practice to explicitly filter by {isNew: false}? Why it's never mentioned in guides? And what's really going on when I ask for all records: why there is my newly created record AND some empty record. I just can't get it after backbone.js where (as I remember after year of not using it) newly created and saved record just changes its state from new to persisted and stays in collection.